# How to store return data from multiple async requests using HttpClient() until all requests complete?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I need to iterate through a series of post requests for data from a url. The requests need to be async. What is the best way to check all returns have completed, and to store that data until all data returned? Prefer to use HttpClient()

Code snippet:

```
     HttpContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);           
     HttpResponseMessage response =  client.PostAsync("/mydata", httpContent).Result; 

     var responsecode = (int)response.StatusCode; 

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         return responseBodyAsText;
     }
     else
     {
         return responsecode +" " +response.ReasonPhrase; 
     }
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, bear in mind that you've got an async problem here:

```
 HttpContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);           

 // whoops! .Result makes this line synchronous.
 HttpResponseMessage response =  client.PostAsync("/mydata", httpContent).Result;

 var responsecode = (int)response.StatusCode; 

 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     return responseBodyAsText;
 }
 else
 {
     return responsecode +" " +response.ReasonPhrase; 
 }
```

Next, since `HttpClient` gives you a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, it seems that you want to have all of the responses, as strings, as something like, say, a `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`, right? We can easily write a function to turn a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` into a `Task<string>`:

```
public async Task<string> ReadResultAsync(Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseTask)
{
    var response = await responseTask;

    var responsecode = (int)response.StatusCode; 

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseBodyAsText;
    }
    else
    {
        return responsecode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase; 
    }
}
```

Now let's say you've got some collection of post data that you need to turn into this async collection of strings, called `myData`:

```
// bear in mind, this code doesn't (necessarily) need to be in a
//  method marked "async". If you want to await on resultsTask, though,
//  it would need to be in an async method.

var tasks = myData
    .Select(x => new FormUrlEncodedContent(x)) //  IEnumerable<FormUrlEncodedContent>
    .Select(x => client.PostAsync("/mydata", x)) // IEnumerable<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>
    .Select(x => ReadResultAsync(x)) // IEnumerable<Task<string>>
    .ToArray(); // Task<string>[]

var resultsTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks); // here is Task<string[]>
```

Comment: Hi FMM When I call var tasks = myData .Select... does it need to be in a parallel.foreach loop or a simple foreach loop? And then call var resultsTask = Task... after the loop has finished?

Comment: No reason to use a parallel foreach loop unless you've got enough items in that collection that you need to farm it out to multiple cores.

Comment: Hi are you able to outline in more detail how you build up the link statement? Also, the main priority, can var resulsTask be called in a method that is itself not async? (to avoid a chain of methods having to become async!) Ta

Comment: Added some comments to hopefully help answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

write a an asynchronous function that fires your post data (i just used your code, please add correct error/exception handling):

```
async Task<string> PostDataAsync(Dictionary<string, string> postData)
{
    var httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);           
    var response = await client.PostAsync("/mydata", httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false); 

    var responsecode = (int)response.StatusCode; 

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return responseBodyAsText;
    }
    else
    {
       return responsecode +" " +response.ReasonPhrase; 
    }
}
```

Now, let's say you have a list of post data 'List> postDataCollection`, then build your requests

```
var postRequests = postDataCollection.Select(pd => PostDataAsync(pd)).ToArray();
```

and then wait for all of them to finish

```
var postResponses = await Task.WhenAll(postRequests);
```

Comment: Hi esskar have you used a dictionary for speed?

Comment: @Steve, no i just checked the constructor documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent.formurlencodedcontent(v=vs.118).aspx